# Find most occurring items in database table

Tags: sql, database, laravel

I have an SQL database table with each row containing an item with `5 columns`:

`id` - unique id of the item

`user_id` - id of the owner of the item

`name` - the exact user input

`simp_name` - simplified user input (remove whitespace and capitals for better matching)

`simp_id` - this id is the same for each item with the same simp_name

I need to find the **Top 10 most popular items**. This means I have to find the items with the same `simp_id` that occur the most in the table. I was looking at the `COUNT()` function, but is this the most efficient way?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What does your current sql query look like?

Comment: In Laravel (Eloquent) I have the query Item::select('simp_name')->where(simp_id = $simp_id), and then loop over this statement with all possible simp_id's and check which queries give the most rows. This seems very slow and cumbersome so I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume it should be something like this:

```
$items = DB::table('your_table')
                ->select('simp_id', DB::raw('count(id) as count_id'))
                ->groupBy('simp_id')
                ->orderBy('count_id','desc')
                ->take(10)
                ->get();
```